# Ionic 6 Angular ion-datetime picker width

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic6

I am trying to adjust the size of the time columns/buttons in the new IONIC 6 timepicker:

[image]

The generated HTML/css is as follows:

[image]

It should be as simple as setting the min-width property on the ion-picker-column-internal, or by setting the width of the picker-item class, however, none of my styles are being applied.

Ex.

```
ion-picker-column-internal {
  min-width: 50px !important;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't, those parts are in the shadow dom. and the docs don't provide anyway to add custom css. https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/datetime#css-shadow-parts